# "-sh: ip: not found" with ip.iproute2 in Yocto Image

Tags: linux, yocto

I am getting an error `-sh: ip: not found` in a Yocto distribution when using the ip.iproute2 package (ip is symlinked to ip.iproute2, trying to run ip.iproute2 directly also gives the same error - `-sh: ip.iproute2: not found`).
If I leave ip.iproute2 out of the build then the ip command works fine, and oddly if I use the meta-updater (OSTree) layer in conjunction with the ip.iproute2 package then it also works fine.

ip.iproute2 is present in the /sbin folder, and `ldd ip.iproute2` gives

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7ed10000)
libelf.so.1 => /usr/lib/libelf.so.1 (0x76e40000)
libmnl.so.0 => /usr/lib/libmnl.so.0 (0x76e20000)
libcap.so.2 => /lib/libcap.so.2 (0x76e00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x76ce0000)
/usr/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76f4a000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x76cb0000)
```

What might the problem be, or how can I go about debugging this?

Comment: `ip.iproute2` might exist, but it's looking for `ip`. Does that executable exist?

Comment: Yes, ip is a symlink to ip.iproute2. I get the same error if trying to run ip.iproute2 directly: ```-sh: ip.iproute2: not found```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/771569/possible-reasons-for-the-shells-not-found-response?noredirect=1#771569. The issue is that the dynamic loader, ```ld-linux-armhf.so.3``` is not present under ```/usr/lib``` but rather under ```/lib```, and the kernel's ELF loader is not as smart as ```ldd```'s resolver to make the ```=>``` link. The next question is why Yocto is producing this issue?